# How to add one UIView object on other UIView object programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uiview

Consider this as my SubView

```
UIView *subViewObj;
```

and this as MainView

```
UIView *mainViewObj;
```

I need to make MainView as root View
can I don it in this way?

```
[mainViewObj addSubview:subViewObj];
```

is this correct? I need to do it programmatically, without using Interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `addSubview:` is correct.

Comment: ok... should i everytime do this before using mainViewObj or subViewObj? 

CGRect cgRect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,480,320); mainViewObj = [[UIVIew alloc]initWithFrame:cgRect];mainViewObj.autoResizeSubviews = YES;

Comment: It depends.  I do not know how mainViewObj was created, but if you wanted subViewObj to fill the entire bounds of its superview (mainViewObj), you would set subViewObj's frame.size to that of mainViewObj and set subViewObj.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight. `autoresizesSubviews` is YES by default so you need not set it every time.